# Помогите разобраться с EJB

Tags: java-ee

Доброго времени, уважаемые.

[Здесь](https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/master/ejb-remote) пример простого *Stateless/Stateful Session Beans*. Там два *maven*-модуля собранных в один *pom*-файл. Я этот пример выполнил. Задеплоил его в *Jboss*. Но, черт побери, как я могу использовать его в своей программе. Его - это калькулятор (*@Remote interface RemoteCalculator*). Как мне дернуть его?

В *RemoteEJBClient.java* есть `public static main`. Но зачем она там, если это все кидается на сервер?

Answer (score 1):

В README к примеру же написано:

> There are two components to this
> example:
>
> 1. A server side component:
>
>    The server component is comprised of a stateful EJB and a stateless EJB.
>    It provides both an EJB JAR that is
>    deployed to the server and a JAR file
>    containing the remote business
>    interfaces required by the remote
>    client application.
>    2. A remote client application that accesses the server component.
>
>    The remote client application depends on the remote business
>    interfaces from the server component.
>    This application looks up the
>    stateless and stateful beans via JNDI
>    and invokes a number of methods on
>    them.

Разворачивайте серверную часть на сервере, запускайте клиента как обчное java приложение из консоли java RemoteEJBClient должно работать.

> ### Build and Deploy the Quickstart
>
> Since this quickstart builds two
> separate components, you can not use
> the standard *Build and Deploy*
> commands used by most of the other
> quickstarts. You must follow these
> steps to build, deploy, and run this
> quickstart.
>
> 1. Make sure you have started the JBoss server. See the instructions in
>    the previous section.
> 2. Open a command prompt and navigate to the ejb-remote quickstart directory
> 3. Build and install the server side component:
>
>    - Navigate to the server-side subdirectory:
>
>      cd server-side
>          * Build the EJB and client interfaces JARs and install them in
>      your local Maven repository.
>
>      ```
>      mvn clean install        
>      * Deploy the EJB JAR to your server. This maven goal will deploy
>      ```
>
>      `server-side/target/jboss-ejb-remote-server-side.jar`.
>      You can check the JBoss server console
>      to see information messages regarding
>      the deployment.
>
>      ```
>      mvn jboss-as:deploy
>      ```
>
>      1. Build and run the client application
>
>         - Navigate to the server-side subdirectory:
>
>         cd ../client
>             * Compile the client code
>
>         mvn clean compile
>             * Execute the client application within Maven
>
>         mvn exec:exec

Собственн, что тут непонятного?

Comment: понимаете, меня сбивают с толку pom-ники. вы смотрели главный pom.xml? там же ясно видно, что весь проект состоит и 2 модулей:
<modules>
  <module>server-side</module>
  <module>client</module>
</modules>
Плюс,меня сбило то,что в server-side плагином:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.ejb.plugin}</version>
</plugin>
собирается удаленный client-кий jar-ник.%)
я должен сделать 2 отдельных проекта: server-side(задеплоить 2 jar) и client-консльное приложение. так? если да, то у меня ошибки сыпятся... = (

Comment: все! Ура!!! заработало! сделал все как написал выше.
странно, в прошлый раз делал все то же самое, и никак....
спасибо за внимание!